# Why does this Javascript code inside a non-Javascript browser have extra commenting?

Tags: javascript

On the [W3 tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp), it shows htis code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then it says:

> The two forward slashes at the end of comment line (//) is the
>   JavaScript comment symbol. This prevents JavaScript from executing the
>   --> tag.

This doesn't make sense to me. I thought the whole thing got commented out.

Comment: That is a *very old* legacy snippet. It only mattered on browsers that *did not support the <script> element*, even to just ignore it, and was there to "keep them from showing the JavaScript".

Comment: @pst - Yes, I will keep in mind that W3 tutorials may have some older and less-relevant material, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, W3Schools has *nothing* to do with W3. Their tutorials were pretty horrible before people started complaining and their confusing name implies that they are somehow connected to W3, but in reality they aren't.

Second of all, this method is not needed anymore. There are no used browsers that don't support JS cleanly (`links`, `lynx`, etc. have no troubles with JS code whatsoever).

That being said, the code is supposed to do this:

```
<!--
I am a HTML comment
-->

<!--
If I am placed in a JS block, the web browser should ignore me
alert('and me');
-->

<!--
If you comment out the HTML comment ending tag, apparently 
the browser will treat the comment as JS code *only* 
if the browser supports JS.
//-->
```

Comment: Note that JavaScript has a special "syntax exception" where it will ignore a `<!--` at the *start* of a `<script>` block, just for this purpose... and the `//` is required because this hack doesn't extend to the `-->` (which is just a JS comment in this case as it follows the `//` on the line ;-)

Comment: Silly backwards-compatibility stuff.

Answer (score 6):

In browsers that *do* understand JavaScript the opening `<--` html comment is ignored and the JS code is executed. The *JS* comment `//` on the last line then prevents the closing `-->` being taken as an error by the JS engine. In browsers that don't understand JavaScript everything between `<--` and `-->` is taken as an html comment and ignored.

This whole thing was a precaution for *older* browsers that didn't know about JS. It is not necessary for any modern browser.

If you want to comment out a block of JS enclose the block in `/*` and `*/`.

Answer (score 1):

If you make it like this, you'll get syntax error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
-->
</script>
```

JavaScript doesn't know HTML's comment closing `-->`, so it has to be commented out of script.
There is no need to use HTML-comments to separate JavaScript, except if you're using a simple text editor which colours the code (NoteTab etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It does all get commented out.

In a bowser without Javascript everything between `<!--` and `-->` will be commented out.

Try to think of it this way:
If you tried this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
-->
</script>
```

then Javascript would throw an error.